# Where should I place the login and logout in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am beginner at Django. I was wondering what is the best practice to place the user login and logout functions. I already have a global static folder and templates.
Should I create a view.py under my **Project-Root** folder for the functions? Or should I create a separate APP just to put this functions in?
I already have this functions and templates inside **myapp** view.py

```
projectname]/                  <- project root 
├── [projectname]/              <- Django root
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings/
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── myapp/
│   ├─ __init__.py
│   └── view.py
│
├── manage.py
│
├── static/
│   └── GLOBAL STATIC FILES
└── templates/
    └── GLOBAL TEMPLATES
```

Comment: There is no specific place to place it, I would suggest creating a new  app because you can extend at easy. When your project grows you will definitely know where to look at.

Answer (score 1):

You should use some user authentication within one App which you have created, or create one App just for managing accounts.

Since you are a beginner you should take a look at Django-admin user authentication.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear as to what you want to place. Is the template files you want to place in or the view function "logout" and "login"? I assume it has to be the "login" and "logout" function what you are looking for.

You have to create a `views.py` file under "[projectname]/apps" folder.

## view for login

```
def login_validate(request):
      if request.method == "POST":
          username = request.POST['username']
          password = request.POST['password']
          user = authenticate(username= username, password= password)
          if user is not None:
             login(request,user)
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/--template name--/')

          else:
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/--template name--/')

       else:
             return HttpResponseRedirect('/--template name--/')
```

## view for logout

```
    def logout_page(request):
        logout(request)
        return render(request,"logout_page.html",{})
```

Above are the functions. You will have to add few things in `settings.py` before doing this.

And also create a `urls.py` file under apps folder and link it to main `urls.py` file.

I hope this is clear.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMGtdtNR4es

The above links are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is quite subjective i.e. varies from project to project, or developer to developer. My suggestions 'd be:

1. As you have asked for the log-in and log-out functions, this means you'll be handling users for your app - so a good approach 'd be to have a `users` app, and place the functions in `users/views.py`
2. For complex system - where you may have different types of users i.e. users, admin_users, partners, etc. You can have separate directory at project root e.g. `lib/` and have `functions.py` in it, keep all the project wide usable functions, utilities in this file.

   > ```
   > projectname]/                  <- project root 
   > ├── [projectname]/              <- Django root
   > │   ├── __init__.py
   > │   ├── settings/
   > │   ├── urls.py
   > │   └── wsgi.py
   > ├── myapp/
   > │   ├─ __init__.py
   > │   └── view.py
   > │
   > ├── lib/
   > │   ├─ __init__.py
   > │   └── functions.py
   > │
   > ├── manage.py
   > │
   > ├── static/
   > │   └── GLOBAL STATIC FILES
   > └── templates/
   >     └── GLOBAL TEMPLATES
   > ```